# Optimization algorithms that does not depend on initial solution

Tags: optimization

I know some optimization algorithms, such as hill-climbing, simulated-annealing, genetic algorithm.

All of the three I mentioned depend on the initial solutions, i.e., the initial solutions may have a great impact on the quality of the final optimal solution.

I wonder if there are any optimization algorithms that don't depend on initial solutions, at least not as much as these three.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the idea of optimization that you start somewhere and try to improve the current solution? Related matter on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization#Classification_of_critical_points_and_extrema

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your list the ant colony optimization. It uses waves of ants and pheromons and a roulette wheel simulation to improve the solution. But the input is also an initial solution.

Comment: It's OK and necessary to have an initial solution as input, but I wonder if any algorithm can reduce the impact of initial solution as much as possible.

Comment: @SpiritZhang: Christofides algorithm gives you a guarantee to be within a certain optimum.

Comment: Thanks for the information! But I see that is an algorithm specified to the TSP. Is there anything that is more general ?

Comment: @SpiritZhang: It depends on your problem. Christofides is good for euklidian space. It satisfy the triangle inequality. If you have other metric it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithms you're referring to are meta-heuristics. They work on a "meta" level i.e. on the top of other heuristics. That said, they try to "improve"-"optimize" a solution produced by some other heuristics in an iterative way via a systematic procedure. So they DO REQUIRE at least an initial solution. Some of them are population-based, so they require more than one solutions.

A very important correction:
"the initial solutions may have a great impact on the quality of the final optimal solution"

One of the key success factor of a metaheuristic is its insensitivity to the initial solution quality.

But, SO it's not the place for that kind of questions. I use [or-exchange](http://www.or-exchange.com/) instead